# Best abbreviation of Real-End User Experience?

Tags: terminology, users, wording

I know user experience is commonly abbreviated UX.
What about composita?

**Real end-user experience monitoring** (usually some kind of passive monitoring) is often called just *Real User Experience*. So I was wondering whether the most intuitive and accepted abbreviation is indeed RUE or something similar rUX, because I also found stuff like RUM or EUM and now I am completely confused.
Any opinions of people from the field are warmly welcome! I try to summarize some info on that and wanted to make sure that I am using the right terminology. So basically I need one or two abbreviations for

- **Real end-user experience monitoring**
- *Real User Experience*

that are not only used by one vendor, but straight forward for people also from other fields.

I found for example those underneath:

- ORACLE: RUEI
- WUERTH PHOENIX: RUE in their description, the logo evidences R. U. X.
- NEW RELIC & MONITIS: RUM
- OTHERS: EUM

[image]

Comment: Is there... Fake User Experience...?

Comment: I can't speak for the whole industry, but this "real" monitoring is not something I've ever heard of or used. Adding the word "real" to the name gives off a strong [methinks-the-lady-doth-protest-too-much](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_lady_doth_protest_too_much,_methinks) vibe, to me. If it were me, I think I'd just abandon that term altogether in favor of something more descriptive and accurate. (I don't think you can actually monitor an "experience" passively, so what are you *actually* monitoring?)

Comment: as far as I understood so far it is actually passive network or application performance monitoring and user experience is deduced from the registered performance metrics... active monitoring means that a performance metric has been registered as a reaction (e.g. simulated network activity), passive monitoring (the part that i called real end-user experience) stands for monitoring traffic that has been caused by end-users without any provocation of such. :-)

Comment: Isn't this a synonym of multivariate testing?

Comment: I think this is too short for a name, you should try "Real Responsive Unobtrusive Rich Dynamic User Experience Behaviour Analysis Software Application" (RRURDUEBASA).

Comment: ^ Rich Experience Dynamically Real Unobtrusive Multivariates (REDRUM)

Comment: REDRUM should sound great, at least to Thrash-Metal fans :-)

Answer (score 0):

Those terms are pretty unpopular. Only to the marketing guys of the software companies you researched.

Probably you are looking for the word "Web Analytics" and if you need abbreviation use WA, althouth there is no need for one because this gives additional hurdles to the users trying to remember what that RUEI thing means.